# Print lines after the scheduler executes the batch script 10 times

Tags: batch-file

I have a windows batch script that is executed by a scheduler after every 1 hour.

I want that certain lines in the batch script to only be executed when  the scheduler has executed the batch script 10 times.

myscript.bat sample

```
@echo off
echo hello world
```

want the below line to print after every 10 times the batch script(myscript.bat) has been executed.

`echo This text will appear after repeating "hello world" for 10 times.`

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: you would need to create a tag file and set something in the file, read it each time until you meet a specific count, then do something else. I will create an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using looping statements 
In your batch file

**For eg :-if you want to print hello world 10 time**

```
 FOR /F %i IN (1,1,10) DO echo hello_world
```

Comment: You missed the question completely.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a file, seeing as the script executes and exits all the time, well each hour in fact.

```
@echo off
echo Hello World
echo Hello World >> lockfile.txt
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=findstr /R /N "^^" lockfile.txt | find /C "Hello""

for /f %%a in ('!string!') do set number=%%a
echo %number%
IF "%number%"=="10" (ECHO Success! && del /Q lockfile.txt)
```

So to explain...
We echo `Hello world`, purely for you to see it in the screen.
We echo `Hello world` to a lockfile each time the script executes.
We do a count of the rows in the file, once we hit 10 rows (in this case 10 executions, then we echo `Success` and we delete the lockfile. The reason for the lockfile deletion is purely to make sure that we do not exceed a count of `10`

So all of the commands you want to run after `hello world` was echo'd 10 times will for part of your `IF` statement. Hope that helps.